# Passthrough USB on hyperv with enhanced mode stopped working

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am working on Windows 10 Pro VM hosted on hyper-v. I need to passthrough usb (mobile device connected in usb port in my case) to VM for remote debugging purpose (cordova run android). I tried this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect. With enabled enhanced mode, usb device (phone) was successfully mounted and visible in VM and debug was working. After VM restart i cannot connect phone to VM anymore. I spent hours on it and cannot find any solution nor reason why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a product like : http://usbip.sourceforge.net/